# Given a string,return an integer as some of all numbers found in the string

Tags: string

Given a string,return an integer as some of all numbers found in the string.

Example:

input :  xyzonexyztwothreeeabrminusseven
output:  1+23+(-7)=17

Comment: and what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a regular expression to match any character that's not an integer and remove it from the string.

As an example, you can easily do this in Java with the following:

```
"input-xyzonexyztwothreeeabrminusseven output-1+23+(-7)=24".replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
```

Which will output as:
123724

Comment: i think you got it in wrong way!                                                                                                 input string :   xyzonexyztwothreeeabrminusseven                                            
 Exp. output:    1+23+(-7)=17                                                                                 so answer is 17

Comment: After your edit the question looks clearer.  Although it would help to know what is the purpose of this. And how should the function work out the operators that you include in your expected output. (i.e. How does xyzonexyztwothree translate into 1+23...)